# Pivot Table on Excel reading from Postgres Table

Tags: excel, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a simple Postgresql table like above. I would like to have it as pivot table in excel/google sheets. But instead of dump all the table to a sheet and then generate a pivot table, I would like to bind it to my postgresql table. I know that I could use power query, but I tought that it is so simple.. that probably an add-in/on could solve it.

```
COUNTRY REVENUE POPULATION
BR      1000    10000
US      2000    20000
MX      3000    30000
AR      4000    40000
```